# Adding extra hard disk to an Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, mount, storage

I have installed a hard disk to my ubuntu machine

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs             1634316       1512   1632804   1% /run
/dev/sdb3       959783984  800733056 110222820  88% /
tmpfs             8171564      97208   8074356   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120          4      5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/sdb2          524252       6220    518032   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1      1953512444 1953198512    313932 100% /hdd
tmpfs             1634312         36   1634276   1% /run/user/119
tmpfs             1634312         60   1634252   1% /run/user/1000
```

and it is mounted on /hdd.

I am just wondering how can I use it in a way that the files from zoneminder are also stored on it?

Currently, zoneminder files are stored in :

```
/var/cache/zoneminder/events/2
```

Is it possible to do it so that the hdd seems like it is an extension of /dev/sdb3? I don't really want to modify the code to utilize hdd for storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to skin this cat, but without rebuilding your system (eg to make use of LVM) you can't make it appear as an extention of /dev/sdb3.

I do comment that /hdd is full at the moment so you will probably want to wipe it before doing anything.

What you can do is (for example) create a subdirectory on /hdd and then symlink  /var/cache/zoneminder to that subdirectory.

After clearing space on /hdd, maybe something like the following in a bash shell -

```
mkdir /hdd/zoneminder
mv /var/cache/zoneminder/* /hdd/zoneminder
rmdir /var/cache/zoneminder
ln -s /var/cache/zoneminder /hdd/zoneminder
```

The above will create a new directory on your new HD, then migrate the data to it.

This does, of-course, assume that /hdd is being automatically mounted.

There is another way to handle this, and that would be to have /dev/sda1 mount to /var/cache/zoneminder   - you may be able to do this by modifying your /etc/fstab table (and you would need to migrate the data to its new location as well).  I'd argue that this is less flexible and a less desireable way of doing it.

I have assumed that this is a regular computer/laptop and playing around with JBOD in the BIOS is not an option.

If reinstalling is an option, reinstall the OS, but use LVM.  In that way you can merge the 2 disks into a single larger disk, and have a lot more control of disk management.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will follow the symlink option. Yes, it is a regular desktop. Also, reinstalling is something I don't really want to do as I had to do some customization to zoneminder to work with my setup. Don't really want do go down that path again.